# Chart messing zoom on ResetAutoValues

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, zooming

I´m using a chart to plot some infos from a Sensor. Everything is going right, until I reach the interval of 3660 points.
So, what I want to do is when my points reach that value, my chart will remove the first point and add the new one, take a look at the code:

```
if (graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.Count > 3660)
{
    graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
    graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), _sensorCampoEletroMagnetico.kVm);
    graficoKVm.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

The problem is that, if the chart is zoomed, when it execute the `graficoKVm.ResetAutoValues();` my zoom got messed up.
So far I´ve tried to store the zoom values and then apply the zoom after the reset, but I´ve failed implementing it. Here is the chart declaration:

```
this.graficoKVm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.graficoKVm.BorderSkin.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 45;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
chartArea1.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.MinorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 5D;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
chartArea1.AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.AxisX2.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisX2.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chartArea1.AxisX2.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisX2.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
chartArea1.AxisX2.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.AxisY.Interval = 2D;
chartArea1.AxisY.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chartArea1.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = 18D;
chartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = -18D;
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0.5D;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 0.5D;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
chartArea1.AxisY.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.AxisY2.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.AxisY2.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chartArea1.AxisY2.ScrollBar.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
chartArea1.AxisY2.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
chartArea1.AxisY2.ScrollBar.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chartArea1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.CursorX.Interval = 0.01D;
chartArea1.CursorX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorX.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorY.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
chartArea1.InnerPlotPosition.Auto = false;
chartArea1.InnerPlotPosition.Height = 91.06797F;
chartArea1.InnerPlotPosition.Width = 95F;
chartArea1.InnerPlotPosition.X = 5F;
chartArea1.InnerPlotPosition.Y = 2.16495F;
chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
chartArea1.Position.Auto = false;
chartArea1.Position.Height = 97F;
chartArea1.Position.Width = 97F;
this.graficoKVm.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
this.graficoKVm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 270);
this.graficoKVm.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.graficoKVm.Name = "graficoKVm";
series1.BorderWidth = 2;
series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
series1.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
series1.Name = "Valor";
series1.ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
series1.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;
this.graficoKVm.Series.Add(series1);
this.graficoKVm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1201, 295);
this.graficoKVm.TabIndex = 27;
this.graficoKVm.Text = "chart1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work in the right way, I've done this implementation:

```
if (graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.Count > 3659)
{
    graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToOADate(), _sensorCampoEletroMagnetico.kVm);
    if (!graficoKVm.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.IsZoomed &&
        !graficoKVm.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.IsZoomed &&
        !graficoKVm.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.ScaleView.IsZoomed &&
        !graficoKVm.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
    {
        while (graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.Count > 3660)
        {
            graficoKVm.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        graficoKVm.ResetAutoValues();
    }
}
```

So, if the chart is zoomed on any Axis, it will not reset the min and max value from each Axis. Eliminating the zoom problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried in your code to use `Refresh` or `Update`? When the index reaches 3660, the chart will be replotted with the `Point` saved in your series, no matter how much zoom you applied.

Comment: Uhm, maybe I don't get properly your question. Why are you using ResetAutoValues?

Comment: No, you´re right. That´s what it does, but it just make my zoom goes to the minimun value on Y and the minimun value on X. I don´t know, maybe it´s something on my chart properties...

Comment: I don't think that line of code could be that helpful. Removing that, it should not affect your code.

Comment: yes, it is. To my client it only matter the last hour, so I need to maintain 1hr+1minute = (3660 seconds) on my chart. But I´ve found an answer.